# React Component Doesn't Re-render When Custom Hook Value is Updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Summary:
I am having trouble getting a component in my React application to re-render when the currentUser value changes from the useCurrentUser() hook. Despite trying various refactoring and troubleshooting steps, the component only renders once and doesn't update thereafter. I am using Supabase for my database and have verified that other components utilizing useCurrentUser() are showing the correct value. The useEffect in the Main component only logs currentUser once, and the component doesn't update thereafter.

Code:
Here is the code for the Main component, the useCurrentUser() hook, and the relevant context:

```
export default function Main() {
  const [portrait, setPortrait] = useState(false)
  const [landscape, setLandscape] = useState(false)
  const [loginVisible, setLoginVisible] = useState(true)
  const screenRef = useRef()
  const em = useEm()
  const currentUser = useCurrentUser()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentUser)
    if (currentUser?.id) {
      setLoginVisible(false)
    }
  }, [currentUser])

  const version = 'v 2.0.0'

  return (
    <SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider sessionId="asdf">
      <View
        style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100%', width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', flexBasis: 0, flexGrow: 1 }}
        ref={screenRef}
        onLayout={() =>
          screenRef.current.measure((x, y, w, h) => {
            if (w > h) {
              setLandscape(true)
              setPortrait(false)
            }
            if (h > w) {
              setLandscape(false)
              setPortrait(true)
            }
          })
        }
      >
        {portrait && <Portrait />}
        {landscape && <Landscape />}
        {loginVisible && <Login close={() => setLoginVisible(false)} />}
      </View>
    </SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider>
  )
}
```

```
function useCurrentUser() {
  return useContext(CurrentUserContext)
}
```

```
function useSupabaseUsers() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({})
  const [userChannel, setUserChannel] = useState()

  async function checkAnonymousId() {
    let anon = ''
    const [[, oldAnon], [, displayName]] = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['@anonymous_user_id', '@anonymous_user_displayname'])

    anon = oldAnon
    if (!oldAnon) {
      const newAnon = uuid.v4()
      AsyncStorage.setItem('@anonymous_user_id', newAnon)
      anon = newAnon
    }

    const channel = supabase.channel('*')
    channel
      .on('presence', { event: 'sync' }, () => {
        const state = channel.presenceState()
        const keys = Object.values(state).map(([user]) => user)

        setCurrentUser(keys.filter(x => x.anon_key === anon)[0])
        setUsers(keys)
      })
      .subscribe(async status => {
        if (status === 'SUBSCRIBED') {
          await channel.track({ anon_key: anon, anon_displayName: displayName })

          supabase.auth.getUser().then(handleAuth)

          supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(() => {
            supabase.auth.getUser().then(handleAuth)
          })
        }
      })

    function handleAuth({ data }) {
      if (data) channel.track({ anon_key: anon, anon_displayName: displayName, id: data.user.id, name: data.user.user_metadata.name })
    }

    setUserChannel(channel)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAnonymousId()
  }, [])

  return [users, currentUser, userChannel]
}
```

Troubleshooting Steps:

- I have refactored the useCurrentUser() hook several times and also tried putting it into a ContextProvider, but the component still doesn't re-render when currentUser changes.
- Other components that use the useCurrentUser() hook correctly show the updated value, so I know the database is working.
- I have tried passing user = {...user} in at various steps but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Question:
Why isn't the Main component re-rendering when the currentUser value changes from the useCurrentUser() hook, and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider wrapper in main component's return value so useCurrentUser is calling outside of that provider. Context consumer will work properly inside context provider.
I think you should declare another component more in wrapper SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider like this:

```
function Wrapper() {
  const [portrait, setPortrait] = useState(false)
  const [landscape, setLandscape] = useState(false)
  const [loginVisible, setLoginVisible] = useState(true)
  const screenRef = useRef()
  const em = useEm()
  const currentUser = useCurrentUser()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentUser)
    if (currentUser?.id) {
      setLoginVisible(false)
    }
  }, [currentUser])

  const version = 'v 2.0.0'

  return (
      <View
        style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100%', width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', flexBasis: 0, flexGrow: 1 }}
        ref={screenRef}
        onLayout={() =>
          screenRef.current.measure((x, y, w, h) => {
            if (w > h) {
              setLandscape(true)
              setPortrait(false)
            }
            if (h > w) {
              setLandscape(false)
              setPortrait(true)
            }
          })
        }
      >
        {portrait && <Portrait />}
        {landscape && <Landscape />}
        {loginVisible && <Login close={() => setLoginVisible(false)} />}
      </View>
  )
}

export default function Main() {
 return (
  <SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider sessionId="asdf">
   <Wrapper/>
  </SupabaseBoardStateContextProvider>
 )
}
```

Comment: Yes of course you're right. I there were 2 different reasons this wasn't working but you obviously can't use context outside of the Provider. So dumb!